# How to convert 5½ to 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel

For my application, I need to receive data from a customer (A product list) and map the information to my database. Before sending it there I need to format it to a specific standard.

Now I have a few cases where the list includes ½ instead of .5 or ,5. The format checker needs to be able to read these characters and change them.

I have never worked with these kinds of characters before. I found HTML will understand the HTML version (½) of the character but as my code uses a str_split() it seems to destroy it in the process. The code may get input like 1.000,25 (becomes 1000.25) or 5½ (becomes 5.5)

```
    $arrayToCheck = Array(
        array(',' , '.'),
        array('¼' , '.25'),
        array('½' , '.5'),
        array('¾' , '.75')
    );

    $inputArrayed = str_split($input);

    foreach ($inputArrayed as &$single){

        foreach ($arrayToCheck as $check){
            if($single == $check[0]){
                $single = $check[1];
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the idea is that I create a list of characters the code needs to look for and what it has to change it into. This list has to be able to be expanded easily. But as it does not recognize these characters it can't change them as I want. Is there any way for my code to recognize this kind of characters?

Comment: The first thing, I would be concerned about, is the encoding. `½` is probably contained in multiple encodings (e.g. [Window-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) as well as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)). However, the codes might be different. (In Windows-1252 and Unicode it's 189 in both cases but I wouldn't rely on this.)

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that I cannot be sure whether it is one of these characters. What happens if this would be used on a normal number or a comma?